# Irrational Natural Density

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Are there any sets of natural numbers with irrational natural density? 
I.e., does there exist a set $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$
\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{|A \cap [1,n]|}{n} \not\in \mathbb{Q}\\
$$

I'd be interested in a proof of existence/nonexistence or an example of such a set

Thanks!

Comment: Some wikipedia'ing finds that the density of the squarefree integers is $\frac 6 \pi^2$, which is irrational because $\pi^2$ is irrational. Any other interesting examples?

Comment: You can build a set with any desired density $\alpha\in(0,1)$: include integers until the density up to that point exceeds $\alpha$, then omit them until it drops below $\alpha$, then include them until it exceeds $\alpha$, etc.

Comment: Drat! My answer took longer to type than your comment - I will delete it. Too late - it seems to have been accepted - sorry @BrianM.Scott

Comment: sorry @BrianM.Scott, hope I didn't violate any etiquette here. I just accepted his because it was a full answer and didn't know if/how to accept a comment

Comment: @OldJohn,user43228: Not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $A=\{\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, and $\alpha$ could be any irrational number greater than $1$. Because $\alpha n - 1\leq \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor \leq \alpha n$, then$$\frac{1}{\alpha} \leq \lim \frac{n}{\alpha n}\leq \lim \frac{n}{\lfloor \alpha n \rfloor} \leq \lim \frac{n}{\alpha n-1}=\frac{1}{\alpha}.$$

It's not obvious but the squeeze above really gives the natural density of $A$. 
Proof:
For any infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$, its elements can be arranged to a strictly increasing sequence $(a_{k})$. Note that the subscript 'counts' the number of $A$. Then $\forall (big)n \in \mathbb{N}$, there must exists a natural number $k$ such that $$a_{k} \leq n \leq a_{k+1},$$
and of course $$k=|A \cap \{ 1,2,…,n\}|.$$
Then
$$\frac{k+1}{a_{k+1}}-\frac{1}{a_{k+1}} \leq \frac{|A \cap \{ 1,2,…,n\}|}{n} \leq \frac{k}{a_{k}}.$$
Taking limit gives the desired result.

Comment: I believe this only shows that the limit of the sequence $\{\frac{\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor}{n}\}$ is $\alpha$

Comment: @aabeshou Sorry for being vague. See my improved answer.

Comment: Looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is not difficult to find a sequence whose natural density is $\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in [0,1]$, rational or irrational. A rough argument goes as follows:

Let $A_n$ be an abbreviation for $\displaystyle\frac{|A \cap [1,n]|}{n}$.

Now construct your sequence $A$ as follows:

Include enough terms to ensure that $A_n$ is greater than $\alpha$, then exclude enough terms to ensure that $A_n$ goes below $\alpha$ etc.

This will always be possible since no matter what the initial segment of $A$ looks like, you can always make $A_n$ tend to zero or 1 by including or excluding all terms from that point on.

Comment: Ah, good point. I suppose this is a simple consequence of the fact that every irrational number is the limit of rational numbers of increasing denominator

Comment: @user43228 Not really. This remark only makes things more complicated, IMHO.

Comment: @Did please elaborate?

Comment: @user43228 To get a set A with density d starting from a sequence with limit d of rational numbers of increasing denominators is more involved than the original problem. Or I am missing something.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't precise enough with what I meant. All I meant is that it's a consequence of the fact that every number betwen 0 and 1 is the limit of some sequence of numbers a_1/b_1, a_2/b_2,...  where a_1=0, a_i is a monotone sequence that increases by at most 1 at a time, and b_i is the sequence 1,2,3,4,...

Comment: How to prove it, Could you explain it in detail?